# Make Spherical Hole on objects in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: unreal, unreal-5

I want to make something like this rasengan effect on a tree for my game (just for learning).

[image]

[Full Video Domonstration Link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uoaJcwkhOU) (length: 1 min)

I am new to unreal engine. So, according to my research so for I can use Procedural Meshes in UE5 and then slice it anywhere but ig that only works with a plan. Also rasengan (that magic/power ball whatever you say lol) works more like an eraser it doesn't just cuts it off rather it vanishes the whole area it collides with.

So, is it possible to create that thing with unreal engine 5?

Comment: You might be able to get away without procedurally modifying the mesh, but instead using shader tricks to create this hole. Search "screen space boolean subtraction shader" for some ideas.

Comment: @DMGregory that was exactly what I needed. Man Thanks a Lot! 

Comment: If you were able to find a solution, be sure to write up the steps in an answer below.

Comment: sure but imma implement it first myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Subtract Boolean operation on mesh to get this result. It requires a plugin "Geometry Script" (which is experimental atm). Found a good [yt video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aVZyHD3Flc) that helped a lot.

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to walk through the steps you took to implement the solution, so that your answer stays useful to future readers, even if that YouTube video goes offline eventually, or is unreachable from another reader's region.